# Sendmail Round-Robin Relay Configuration

Tags: sendmail

I'm trying to configure my mail server to deliver mail to relay servers in round-robin fashion using Linux and sendmail 8.13.8.

I want to achieve the following:

Let's say I run mail.example.com as the mail server, and have relay1, relay2, relay3, and relay4 ready for actual mail delivery.

Five emails arrive to mail.example.com:

mail 1 => relay1.example.com
mail 2 => relay2.example.com
mail 3 => relay3.example.com
mail 4 => relay4.example.com
mail 5 => relay1.example.com

And so forth.

I tried to set this up by defining multiple smart hosts, but it seems like the supplementary hosts only activate if the hosts before them fail.

Clearly that isn't the way. How should this be done correctly?

Comment: Are you asking about email that _arrives_ at your domain (and hence you want to load balance email reception) or are you asking about email that you send and you want to load balance it to five _outgoing_ relays?

Comment: I want to balance to four outgoing relays.

Answer (score 1):

In your sendmail.mc:

> define(SMART_HOST, relay1:relay2:relay3:relay4)dnl

Then according to your distribution's instructions create sendmail.cf and restart sendmail.  In Debian you just type `sendmailconfig`. In CentOS you type `/etc/mail/make` followed by a `service sendmail restart`.

If the relays have MX records, you may need to enclose them in [square brackets](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/configuration_readme/)